# Change Flatlist Scroll Index while coming back to 1st Screen from 2nd Screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

I am working on a broadcasting app, rendering the messages using the flatlist. I want to return from the bookmark screen to the flatlist screen, and scroll to the bookmarked index which I am getting from the bookmark scene. But the scroll is happening after few seconds of returning to the screen. I tried using redux but that doesn't help as well.

The below function is triggered on clicking on a bookmark item to find the index of the bookmarked message from the original list.

```
searchIndex = async (id) => {
    let val = this.state.messages.findIndex(x=>x._id === id)
    console.log(val)
     this.props.navigation.navigate({
       name:'BroadCastScreenTwo',
       params: {jumpValue:val},
       merge:true
     })
  }
```

The below function is called for changing the scroll index.

```
async componentDidMount(){
  const unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', async () => {
     var val= this.props.route.params.jumpValue;
  if(val !== null){
      await this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({
        animated: true,
        index: val,
      });
    }
    });
    unsubscribe;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing animated: true fixed my problem.